# Get updated entities by JPQL UPDATE query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

We can track updated entities using @PostUpdate:

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    ...

    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate() {
        Tracker.trackEntity(this);
    }
}
```

When we update entity using **EntityManager.merge(...)** then **postUpdate()** will be invoked.

But how I can track entities modified using bulk update (**EntityManager.createQuery(...).executeUpdate()**)?

Comment: You would have to use the same where clause in a select statement before executing the update query.

Comment: @Chris that's sad. Anyway thanks for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless you first do a query of the entities affected by that UPDATE query. That is the point of an UPDATE query, it goes straight to the DB and doesn't have hooks for such things as callbacks, or cascading.